# Add User-defined/custom differential equations in OpenFoam (CFD)

Tags: fluid-dynamics, finite-volume, openfoam

I am new to OpenFoam. And I am trying to add a set (user defined) of differential equations to OpenFoam.

I want to solve this user defined set of equations at each time point in addition to standard fluid dynamic equations.

Theoretically,

SET-1 is ODE/PDE's associated with fluid dynamics (equations already there in openfoam)

SET-2 is ODE/PDE's that are defined by user (how to add this set to openfoam is my question)

Could this be done in OpenFoam? does anyone have a sample example?

Thank you so much for your time and attention.

Answer (score 4):

The whole point of the OpenFOAM (OF hereinafter) libraries is exactly what you are inquiring for: PDE mimicking programming for CFD using the FV framework. In order to do what you are asking, you should have a decent foundation in C++ (not necessarily an expert...), of course in FVM and CFD in general. The first step in order to program using the OF framework is to get comfortable using the doxygen browser to dive into the code. Don't get your hopes high if you expect to find a thorough tutorial on OF programming, basically there isn't. You'll have to resort to the OF community or some examples/homeworks/theses that are posted on Chalmers University and foamcfd.com. A good review on the OF framework can be found in the following [link](http://www.ams.org/notices/201404/rnoti-p354.pdf).

Comment: There is also the programmer's guide: https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjj5s7AnpfKAhUCVBoKHWXyAlEQFggiMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffoam.sourceforge.net%2Fdocs%2FGuides-a4%2FProgrammersGuide.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGmgT0fKRzuoZ5hEUMpgYgEHfI5_g&sig2=5fqZlki3RYkaQ55RPvBVng